# A variable in a variable

Tags: swift

Is it possible to place a variable in a variable?

I'm trying to make a game. In this game there are two players. I don't want to type every action twice, but with different players, I would like to use the same thing that's possible in strings.

```
print("String \(variable) rest of string")
```

How can I accomplish the same in a variable?

```
var playerActive : String
var player1Score = 100
var player2Score = 100

if (x==0){
    playerActive = "player1"
}else{
    playerActive = "player2"
}

if (\(playerAvtive)Score) <= 0){ //Must become player1Score or player2Score
    print("You lost...")
}
```

I found the same question for other languages but not for Swift.

Comment: This is when you would want to make a property or struct, instead of just using names to hint at similarity.

Comment: More generally, no, variable names can't be treated as strings (or manipulated at all).

Comment: @aryamccarthy: Thank you for the advise. I will Google it and get myself informed.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: The answer I feared... Thank you for giving it to me in a gentle way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Player` class:

```
class Player {
    var score = 0
}

let player1 = Player()
let player2 = Player()
var playerActive = player1

if (x == 0){
    playerActive = player1
} else{
    playerActive = player2
}

if playerActive.score <= 0 {
    print("You lost...")
}
```

I recommend against using a `struct` instead of a `class`, as you might have to check the winner using `===`.

```
if someoneWon && activePlayer === player1 {
    print("Player 1 won!")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right way. So, to check if I understand it correctly, the best practise would be putting al the variables concerning the player into the Player class and using a dot syntax to change any variables in the Player class?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.